# Django Models and Testing: Failed to install custom SQL

Tags: django, django-models, django-testing

I have the following model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from vehicle.models import Vehicle
from account.models import Wheelster

class Ride(models.Model): 
    [...]
    driver = models.OneToOneField(Wheelster, blank=True)
    driver_vehicle = models.OneToOneField(Vehicle, blank=True) 
    [...]
```

But when I try to run my Django tests, I get the following error.

```
Failed to install custom SQL for ride.Ride model: column "driver" of relation "ride_ride" does not exist
LINE 1: ...RT INTO ride_ride (origin, destination, datetime, driver, dr...
```

It works fine if I change the field types to CharField. Any idea where the error comes from?

Comment: It's probably because the OneToOneField is creating the column in the `Wheelster` table, not in `Ride` table. Can you check this in your sql database?

Comment: They're not. Both fields are created in the Ride table, but they appear as driver_id and driver_vehicle_id. I must be missing something about one-to-one relationships.

Comment: Never mind, I got it. I had a .sql file that generated custom SQL back when the fields were still of type CharField. Thanks for your time!